# asp.net mvc2 form post keeps extending the browser url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-2, http-post

I am trying out ASP.NET MVC2.  I have a controller called SearchController and a view folder called Search containing Search.aspx.
In my controller I have:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Post()
        {
            HPSLucene.Models.Arbitrary arb = new HPSLucene.Models.Arbitrary();
            arb.Title = "Post received";
            return View("Search",arb);
        }
```

In my view I have:

```
<form action="Search/Post" method="post">
    <label><% Response.Write(Model.Title); %></label>
    <input type="Submit" Value="First" Name="submitButton"/>
    </form>
```

It works fine the first time I click the button, and the browser shows a url of http://localhost:1824/Search/Post.  However, when I click the button a second time the browser url changes to http://localhost:1824/Search/Search/Post and I get a 404.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a / at the beginning of your action url.

Why not allow asp.net to deal with this for you and use:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Search")) { %>

<label><% Response.Write(Model.Title); %></label>
<input type="Submit" Value="First" Name="submitButton"/>

<% } %>
```

Which will give you

```
<form action="/Search/Post" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a relative url for the form action.  I suggest using either the UrlHelper the Html form helper.  Both of these will produce suitable absolute urls. Examples with Razor syntax:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action( "post", "search" )" ...
```

or

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm( "post", "search" ))
   {
    ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `action` to `/Search/Post`, but that would break if your app will be installed to a non-root location. A reliable way is to use something like

```
<form action="<%= Url.Content("~/Search/Post") %>" ...
```

Comment: thanks, that works.  However, in this post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx then Scott Guthrie does not use this snippet and presumably his code works ok - any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `BeginForm` HtmlHelper instead of writing the `form` tag manually:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244.aspx

It sounds like the browser is interpreting it as a relative URL and, when the current URL is under `/Search/` then it's making it relative to that.  The HtmlHelper *should* account for this, but YMMV.